# quickinstaller.installProduct 'installs' stuff that doesn't even exist. How do I raise an exception?

Tags: plone

I have a `config.py` in my product, having:

```
DEPENDENCIES = ['bbbbbbbbbbbb'] #This doesn't exist
```

And in my `setuphandlers.py`:

```
for dependency in DEPENDENCIES:
    if not quickinstaller.isProductInstalled(dependency):
        quickinstaller.installProduct(dependency)
```

And now I have a **bbbbbbbbbbbb** entry in my portal_quickinstaller's Contents tab. (http://localhost:8080/Plone/portal_quickinstaller/manage_main).

What should I do to make the dependencies section 'complain' (raise an exception, whatever) if the dependency doesn't exist? Thanks!

**EDIT**: I've found a hack using `quickinstaller.getProductVersion`: if nothing comes, it doesn't exist. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def install_dependencies(site):
    """Install required products"""

    qi = getToolByName(site, 'portal_quickinstaller')
    for product in DEPENDENCIES:
        if not qi.isProductInstalled(product):
            if qi.isProductInstallable(product):
                qi.installProduct(product)
            else:
                raise "Product %s not installable" % product
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of declaring deps is to use `metadata.xml`:

```
<metadata>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.iterate:plone.app.iterate</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

This will add the `plone.app.iterate` package, as its install profile name is `plone.app.iterate`.  The vast majority of these are called default, e.g.:

```
<metadata>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.jquerytools:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-archetypes.referencebrowserwidget:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.imaging:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.registry:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.portlet.collection:default</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

Of course, this only works if the product you're trying to install has a Generic Setup profile, but all but the very oldest do.

Comment: @MatthwmWilkes: that's the problem, I have a really heterogeneous installation. But I'll keep your solution for newer ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends why you might have a product that doesn't exist.

Normally, you wouldn't be testing this here - you'd put your dependency in setup.py, and then your buildout fails if the product doesn't exist.

If, though, you have a product that may use a second product if it exists (for instance, SQLAlchemy needs one or more python DBAPI eggs, but no specific one), then I would think you need to do the usual: which is to wrap an import of some module in the product with a **try/except** and not do the install if the import fails.